# im using cordova to create my apk , i cannot set badge using cordova-plugin-badge , can anyone help me with a working example

Tags: android, cordova, plugins, cordova-plugins, badge

```
cordova.plugins.notification.badge.set(10);
```

this is not working for me , tried in differrent devices

```
cordova.plugins.notification.badge.hasPermission
```

this code returns true can anyone help me

Comment: Are you sure that, your android device showing badge for other apps too ? because many android devices not supported app badge, and you have also the same one.

Comment: my android device is showing badge for other apps ,

Comment: Can you share your code where you have set this line and also make sure that you have added `cordova.js` in your html file.

Comment: <script>
        
        
        //alert(devid);
    $(document).ready(function(){
        
        
        
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
        

        function onDeviceReady() 
        {

            cordova.plugins.notification.badge.hasPermission(function (granted) {
            alert('Permission has been granted: ' + granted);
            
        });
            cordova.plugins.notification.badge.set(10);
        }
    });
    </script>

Comment: yes ive added cordova.js

Answer (score 0):

I have made some changes in your script just try setting the same and let me know if it is working or not

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    function onDeviceReady(){
        cordova.plugins.notification.badge.hasPermission(function(granted){ 
            alert('Permission has been granted: ' + granted);
            cordova.plugins.notification.badge.set(10);
        }); 
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Another question is have you added [Cordova Push Plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push) ?